# Error with php variables, i don't understand

Tags: php, variables

I have a problem with a var in my php code ..
I don't understand how

there is my code :

```
<fieldset>
 <?
 if(isset($_POST['requete']) && $_POST['requete'] != NULL){
   include "connexion.inc";
   $reponse = $bdd->query('SELECT id_piece, piece 
   FROM tbl_piece 
   WHERE piece = '.$requete.' ');
   while($donnees = $reponse->fetch()){
    echo $donnees['id_piece'];
   }
 }
 else{
  echo $requete;
 }
 ?>         
  <form method="post" action="standard.php">
  <input type="text" name="requete">
  <input type="submit" value="Rechercher">
  </form>
  </fieldset>
```

So, on my web page, there is just a text box with a button to validate and " test " onto the textbox, yeh there i understand, my var is ok and all is alright my script is waiting my Keyword to find in my table ok
I write " AD202 " which is present in my table and click on my button
and then i get this error

```
 Notice: Undefined variable: requete in /home/libtronic/www/html/standard.php on line 52
```

and .. i don't understand how to keep my var declared and assigned with my "AD202" keyword

Could you help me :/ ?

Comment: You don't have declared $requete

Comment: Is the file above standard.php? If not please provide the code for that file too...

Comment: maybe you could look at this exact duplicate question : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39470620/sqlstate42000-violation-1064-in-a-select

Comment: Concatenation with a posted variable isn't the way to build a query, see how to bind a parameter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You try to use a variable without defining it first. Also, it would be safer and better practise to use prepared statements within your php code to avoid nasty surprises ( sql injection )

```
<fieldset>
    <?php
        if(isset($_POST['requete']) && $_POST['requete'] != NULL){
            include "connexion.inc";

            /* define the variable!! */
            $requete=$_POST['requete'];

            $reponse = $bdd->query('SELECT id_piece, piece 
                FROM tbl_piece 
                WHERE piece = '.$requete.' ');

            while($donnees = $reponse->fetch()){
                echo $donnees['id_piece'];
            }
        } else{
            echo $requete;
        }
    ?>
    <form method="post" action="standard.php">
        <input type="text" name="requete">
        <input type="submit" value="Rechercher">
    </form>
</fieldset>
```

Answer (score 2):

The error's self-explanatory, your variable, `$requete`, is not defined anywhere in your code.

---

I assume that you are referring to `$_POST['requete']`, to define it you'll need to add a line like this:

```
$requete = $_POST['requete'];
```

And to prevent MySQL injection, you can use `mysqli_real_escape_string`: (`$link` is the connection parameter)

```
$requete = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_POST['requete']);
```

Note: You need to define it before you use the variable which means before `$reponse = ...`

---

Alternatively, if you don't want to define it, you can use `$_POST['requete']` directly, however it might be at risk to SQL injection.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have declared $requete, just add it before your query:

```
$requete = $_POST["requete"];
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is

```
$reponse = $bdd->query('SELECT id_piece, piece 
FROM tbl_piece 
WHERE piece = '.$requete.' ');
```

Either you capture $requete

```
$requete=$_POST['$requete'];
```

before the statement or

Your line should be

```
 $reponse = $bdd->query("SELECT id_piece, piece 
 FROM tbl_piece 
 WHERE piece = '$_POST[requete]'");
```

This is not adviceable as it is open to SQL injection.

Ideally you should sanitize any incoming Variables _POST or _GET before using them for further functions.And the $reponse->fetch() should be better with $response->fetch_assoc()